# Assume we know the distributions of $X $and $h(X)$, how to find $h$?

Tags: functions, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable in $\mathbb{R}$

Let $h:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an *unknown* function

Assume we know the distribution of $X $ and the distribution of $h(X)$

Can one find $h$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we cannot. Consider if $X$ and $h(X)$ are both uniform on $[0,1]$. Then we might have $h(x)=x$, we might have $h(x)=1-x$, and we can't tell which. If we allow discontinuous $h$, then there are *many* functions we could have, starting with
$$
h(x)=\cases{x+\frac12&if $x\leq\frac12$\\1-x&if $x>\frac12$}
$$
and only getting uglier from there.

Comment: If we assume that $h$ is strictly increasing and continuous, is it possible then ?

Comment: @JanVanImpe Not necessarily. Consider $X$ and $h(X)$ both being uniform on $[0,1]\cup [2,3]$. Then we know that $h(1)=1$ and $h(2)=2$, but apart from that, $h$ could be anything on $[1,2]$. However, if $X$ has support on all of $\Bbb R$ (like a normal variable), and we assume $h$ is increasing (not strictly increasing, not continuous; places where $h$ is constant corresponds to single values for which $h(X)$ has positive probability, and discontinuities of $h$ corresponds to disconnections in the support of $h(X)$), then yes, I think we can uniquely determine $h$.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, but your last statement would need some reference or a basic sketchOr (not  if we assume that $X $ has strictly increasing density function

Comment: I meant I did't get the part 

_places where 
$h$
is constant corresponds to single values for which 
$h(X)$
has positive probability, and discontinuities of 
$h$
corresponds to disconnections in the support of 
$h(X)$
), then yes, I think we can uniquely determine 
$h$_


I will think about this later

Answer (score 1):

As made clear by the answer of Arthur $h$ cannot always be found. Extra conditions are needed.

---

First a note that will be used below.

For a CDF $F$ we can define $\Phi_F:(0,1)\to\mathbb R$ by stating:$$\Phi_F(u):=\inf\{x\mid F(x)\geq u\}$$

Then $\Phi_F(F(x))\leq x$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$ and in the special case that $F$ is strictly increasing we find: $$\Phi_F\circ F=\mathsf{id}_{\mathbb R}\tag1$$

---

Let it be that $h$ and $F_X$ are both strictly increasing and let it be that the range of $h$ is not bounded below and is not bounded above. Then $F_{h(X)}$ is also strictly increasing.

Further we have: $$F_{h(X)}(h(x))=P(h(X)\leq h(x))=P(X\leq x)=F_X(x)$$

or shortly:$$F_{h(X)}\circ h=F_X$$

Since $F_{h(X)}$ is strictly increasing then we can apply $(1)$ and find:$$h=\Phi_{F_{h(X)}}\circ F_X$$

I do not exclude that the conditions can be weakened.

Comment: $h=\Phi_{F_{h(X)}}\circ F_X $ where $\Phi$ = quantile function and $F=$ cumulative distribution function